# Mesh rectangular structure

Tags: c#, mesh, voronoi, quadtree, discretization

What is the best way, to mesh a rectangular structure as you can see it here:
[image: Structure to mesh]
What is special here, is the large difference in size between the thin grey structures and the large white gaps. Hence, a regular `recangle-grid` might not be the best option.

I tried a `Quadtree`, where I started with a 10x10 Grid and splitted one cell into four, if the cell contains grey and white structure.
But I get an unnecessary large number of cells.

`Voronoi` might also not be the best choise, since my shape is always perfectly rectangular.

**Is there any way to take into account the shape of the structure from the beginning?**

Comment: Are you looking to create a structured grid or unstructured? What mesh element(s) do you want: triangles, rectangles, quads? Do you have to do it inside your code, or you can use a meshing software/library? Is your structure "fixed" or it is just a structure pattern?

Comment: @AntonMenshov: I guess rectangles are the best, since I only have recangular patterns. I have to do it inside my code, which is in C#. My structure is fixed. The user can set it in the beginning but then it wont't change anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way

Depends on what you mean by "best".

I wouldn't bother so much with the structure and just use any of the existing mesh generators, e.g.,

- [Gmsh](http://gmsh.info) (or [pygmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh/))
- [mshr](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/mshr/src/master/)
- [dmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/dmsh/)
- [MeshPy](https://documen.tician.de/meshpy/)
- ...

and perhaps throw [optimesh](https://github.com/nschloe/optimesh) on it. (Disclaimer: pygmsh, dmsh, optimesh are written by me.)

All of those methods should give you a good triangular mesh to start with.